# JPA: "Column not found" although JPA created the table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to test a batch reading data from a database.

I have an entity such as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class ClientEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "START", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date start;
}
```

When unit testing my batch, I insert data into a memory database thanks to a SQL script read with the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` option while the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` option is set on `create`:

```
Insert into CLIENT(ID, START) values (1,'2006-02-01')
Insert into CLIENT(ID, START) values (2,'2010-02-01')
```

I can see in the log that the table is properly created. Yet, when retrieving the `CLIENT`s further in my code (perhaps through some join), an exception is raised:

```
ERROR - Column "CLIENTENTI0_.START" not found; SQL statement:
    select cliententi0_.ID as ID1_10_, cliententi0_.START 
        as START2_10_ from CLIENT cliententi0_ [42122-165]
```

I have to add that when plugged to an exising Oracle database, the code runs perfectly!

What is wrong with my code? How can I get it to work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to execute with some client for the database the query that the error has printed? What happens, then?

Comment: As I let Hibernate create my tables, I donot know how to access them and see what's actually inside.  Or what is a good way for debugging?

Comment: Well, you must have defined somewhere how to access the database, in some configuration file: persistence.xml, hibernate.cfg.xml or perhaps in the server. If the server is tomcat, it would be in context.xml. If you know how to access the database, you can use an oracle client (for example, toad) to check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well shame on me.

The error came from the fact that the goal of my batch is reading data from a database `A` and to write data to a database `B`.

To test my batch, I set two memory instances. But a mistaken copy and paste made me create twice the same instance... And since there is one `CLIENT` table in `A` and one other `CLIENT` table in `B`, an error was raised when retrieving the data: one of those tables was unproperly created!

Hope this might help someone else!